# VBA "Date" not in new version of Object Library

Tags: excel, vba, date

I upgrade to Office 2016. The Date function does not appear to be in the new Excel 2016 library.

I cannot seem to access the old object library. How do I pull the system date into me VBA code now?

I am surprised that WorkSheetFunction.Today() did not work either. I can't believe I am the only person that faced this issue.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016 ```Date``` is definitely a thing in it.

Comment: What makes you assume that `date` does not appear? How does your code look like? What error do you get? I have used all versions of Excel/VBA since at least 2003 and can assure that `date` and `now` always worked.

Comment: There's no `WorksheetFunction.Today()` either. Not all formulas have a `WorksheetFunction` equivalent.

Comment: I hope it has gone ... having a function with the same name as a datatype was always confusing.

Comment: What code did you use for Date?

Answer (score 1):

"Now" function:

```
Dim dtToday as Date
dtToday = Int(Now) 'Or just Now if you want the time as well
```

Comment: That doesn't answer why `date` seems to be missing for the OP

Comment: @FunThomas OP asked "How do I pull the system date into me VBA code now?" I think this answers that part of the question. So he or she has a way forward at least. Especially since they had tried Today() as as a workaround.

Comment: I would disagree as the `date` function is definitively part of VBA. If the OP doesn't see it there must be a reason, and if you want to survive in programming you need to understand reasons and not go ahead with *"works for me"*.

Comment: Date has been working for me for a very long time. Many of my modules utilize it. I think when my IT people installed 16 it is no longer the the Excel Object Library and the uninstalled the old library. I tried adding every object library under the sun to to see if that one would help. Then I tried worksheet functions.Then a scoured through the object library I found VBA date under class DateTime and seems to work. I also tried olDate, XlDate, vbDate. Maybe when bringing VBA to excel, I need to add the class? Not really sure my solution is the best but the programs are working again.

Comment: @FunThomas Life's just too short. The OP has a way forward it seems, so let's leave it there.

Comment: Hm. Problem for OP is solved, but the real reason was not found. SO used to be a place where questions are asked and answered that are useful also for other users. If someone stumbles over a similar problem, they will not find an answer here, only a possible workaround. I understand you, but that makes SO just another forum for quick answers.

Comment: @FunThomas Perhaps it can be both. Should we deny the OP a workaround on the basis that the underlying issue hasn't been resolved to the community's satisfaction?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I had to use was:

I had to replace "date" with "datetime.date"
I also had to replace "right", "left", "mid", "len" , "instr", "revstr" with:

```
strings.right
strings.left
strings.mid
strings.len
strings.instr
```

Every VBA command I had to add the class as a precedent, for it to work.

Comment: Are you using any references in your code? There must be a reason that those functions need the library.

Comment: I am using both outlook and excel. It used to work. The module is attached to a excel sheet. I code before "Tday= Date" would return #10/2/2020#. I use a function to turn that into 10-02-2020. That matches the auto reports and downloads just the days report, processed them and sends out excel files to people who want the reports.  I have the following references: VBA, MS Excel 16.0 OLE, MSO 16, Outlook 16.0 MS forms 2.0, MS 15.0 Access. I added a few more after the problem. Maybe I should open a blanks sheet and add references one at time to test it.